# Create Matrix from a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix

I have a dataframe with several columns, including Department and ICA. I need to create a matrix where the rows are the departments, and the columns are ICA values (they range from bad-acceptable-good).

So position r,c would be a number that shows how many observations of ICA were recorded for each department.
For example, if Amazonas is row 1 and Acceptable is column 3, position (1,3) would be the number of acceptable observations for Amazonas.

Thanks!

Comment: Include a data sample, the code you've tried and your expected output.

Answer (score -1):

You can get values from your DataFrame using integer-based indexing with the [DataFrame.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) method. This seems to do what you need.

For example, if `df` is your DataFrame, then `df.iloc[0, 2]` will give you the value at the first row and third column.

Comment: Yes, but I dont want the values form the ICA column, I want to count how many times they show up.